# knpuniversity / oauth2-client-bundle - Invalid state

Tags: php, symfony, google-signin

First of all, I'm sorry for my english.
I have a symfony 5.1 app, with php7.4-fpm, apache2.4, Mysql 5.7 under Ubuntu 18.04 (same stack for dev and prod).
I use knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle for google login.
In my dev environment authentication works fine with all main browser on pc, mac, android, iOS.
In my prod environment authentication work fine with all main browser, but only  on pc, mac and android. If I use iOS (iPad and iPhone) with any browser (safari, chrome, firefox), authentication fails with following exception

> "Invalid state parameter passed in callback URL".

The problem seems to be here:

"vendor/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle/src/Client/OAuth2Client.php"

```
/**
 * Call this after the user is redirected back to get the access token.
 *
 * @param array $options Additional options that should be passed to the getAccessToken() of the underlying provider
 *
 * @return AccessToken|\League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessTokenInterface
 *
 * @throws InvalidStateException
 * @throws MissingAuthorizationCodeException
 * @throws IdentityProviderException         If token cannot be fetched
 */
public function getAccessToken(array $options = [])
{
    if (!$this->isStateless()) {
        $expectedState = $this->getSession()->get(self::OAUTH2_SESSION_STATE_KEY);
        $actualState = $this->getCurrentRequest()->get('state');
        if (!$actualState || ($actualState !== $expectedState)) {
            throw new InvalidStateException('Invalid state');
        }
    }

    $code = $this->getCurrentRequest()->get('code');

    if (!$code) {
        throw new MissingAuthorizationCodeException('No "code" parameter was found (usually this is a query parameter)!');
    }

    return $this->provider->getAccessToken(
        'authorization_code',
        array_merge(['code' => $code], $options)
    );
}
```

For some reason the session is NULL, so "$expectedState" is NULL too.
I repeat that the problem occur only with iPad/iPhone (with different browser and different iOS versions) on production vps.
I also tried with a new vps, but the error remain.
I tried to set Symfony env to prod on my develop pc and all works fine.

I'm going crazy.
Someone can help me ?

Thanks